# sumar años a una fecha en php

Tags: php

hola como puedo hacer que mis valores de fecha inicio 2013/01/01  y fecha fin 2013/01/31 se incremente de año en año
mi código hace que se incremente de dos en dos pero no logro hacer que lo haga de uno en uno

```
    $fecha_inicial = date('2013-01-01');
    $fecha_fin = date('2013-01-31');

   for($año = 0; $año <6; $año++){ 

    $fecha_inicial = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_inicial . "+ 1 year"));
    $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 1 year"));
     for ($contador = 0; $contador < 12; $contador++) {
         $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT
        khe.Tiempo,
        khe.Fecha,
        khe.IdArea,
        cc.Nombre
        FROM
        k_horasextras AS khe
        INNER JOIN c_area AS cc ON cc.IdArea = khe.IdArea
        WHERE khe.Fecha > '$fecha_inicial' AND khe.Fecha < '$fecha_fin'
        ORDER BY
        cc.Nombre ASC;";

     echo"<br>$año"."$contador"."$consulta</br>";
     $resultActividades = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
     if(mysql_num_rows($resultActividades)>0){
       while ($rowActividades = mysql_fetch_array($resultActividades)){
        $data[$rowActividades['Nombre']][$contador] +=$rowActividades['Tiempo'];
       }
     }

     $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 1 month"));
     $fecha_inicial = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_inicial . "+ 1 month"));

    if ($contador == 0 ) {
       $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "- 3 days"));
    }

    if ($contador == 1) {
       $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 3 days"));
    }

    }
   }

 }
```

cuando imprimo la consulta me salen estos valores

```
 00SELECT DISTINCT khe.Tiempo, khe.Fecha, khe.IdArea, cc.Nombre FROM 
 k_horasextras AS khe INNER JOIN c_area AS cc ON cc.IdArea = khe.IdArea WHERE 
 khe.Fecha > '2014-01-01' AND khe.Fecha < '2014-01-31' ORDER BY cc.Nombre ASC;

 10SELECT DISTINCT khe.Tiempo, khe.Fecha, khe.IdArea, cc.Nombre FROM 
 k_horasextras AS khe INNER JOIN c_area AS cc ON cc.IdArea = khe.IdArea WHERE 
 khe.Fecha > '2016-01-01' AND khe.Fecha < '2016-02-01' ORDER BY cc.Nombre ASC;

 20SELECT DISTINCT khe.Tiempo, khe.Fecha, khe.IdArea, cc.Nombre FROM 
 k_horasextras AS khe INNER JOIN c_area AS cc ON cc.IdArea = khe.IdArea WHERE 
 khe.Fecha > '2018-01-01' AND khe.Fecha < '2018-01-30' ORDER BY cc.Nombre ASC;
```

Comment: Carlos, acomoda bien tu código que no se le entiende, y hay llaves volando como para tratar de acomodarlo

Comment: ya lo acomode como puedo hacerle?

Answer (score 2):

```
$fecha = "2018-09-04";
for ($año = 0; $año < 6; $año++) {
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha)) . " + 1 year"));
    echo $fecha."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisé tu código y encontré dos errores:

1 - En el fragmento que nos envías hay una llave de cierre de más, que estimo debe cerrar alguna anidación superior que no copiaste.

2 - En las últimas dos funciones incrementás y reducís la fecha de la variable `$fecha_fin` y esta queda envuelta en el segundo `for` que utilizas, eso genera que al terminar el for interno en la primera vuelta de 12 meses tienes los siguientes resultados:

```
$fecha_inicial = 2015-01-01;
$fecha_fin = 2015-02-01;
```

Estos son las nuevas variables que pasan por:

```
$fecha_inicial = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_inicial . "+ 1 year"));
$fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 1 year"));
```

Convirtiendosé en:

```
$fecha_inicial = 2016-01-01;
$fecha_fin = 2016-02-01;
```

Podr'as verlo claramente si agregas un print al final del código de esta manera podrás ver todas las consultas y los valores finales de las variables:

```
if ($contador == 0 ){
    $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "- 3 days"));
}
if ($contador == 1) {
    $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 3 days"));
}
print_r($fecha_inicial);
print_r($fecha_fin);
```

Si utilizas `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 1 month"))` sumará directamente al último día de cada mes sin necesidad de contabilizar los días, así que elimina los últimos dos condicionales y debería andar correctamente.

Saludos!

Comment: gracias por la ayuda :)